# using a dictionary to cut down a list of tuples

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

i'm trying to use a dictionary to cut down a list of tuples.  the starting point is shown below.  i also included a dictionary - the values in the dictionary is what i am trying to use to cut down my list of tuples

```
start = [('bryan', 'lucy'), ('david', 'lucy')]

dic = {'bryan': 4.9, 'lucy': 7.5, 'david': 8.0}
```

i want it so any tuple that has elements with a difference greater than 1 (according to the value in the dictionary) to be removed.  in this case the desired output would be

```
[('david','lucy')]
```

b/c the absolute value of david - lucy = 0.5

here is my (failed) attempt to solve my problem.

```
end = []

for i in range(0,len(start)):
    if abs(dic[start[i][0]] - dic[start[i][1]]) < 1.0001:
        end.append(dic[start[i]])
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension can help you out here.

```
[(e,o) for e, o in start if -1 < dic[e]-dic[o] < 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension can make this a one-liner

```
[ (l,r) for (l,r) in start if abs(dic[l]-dic[r])<1.0001 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
In [13]: [x for x in start if abs(dic[x[0]] - dic[x[1]]) < 1.0001]
Out[13]: [('david', 'lucy')]
```

This is [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) in python. It will check for all attributes in list and compare condition `abs(dic[x[0]] - dic[x[1]]) < 1.0001` element who fulfill this condition will return.

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Comment: :) don't tell me (in a comment), edit your answer... it's part of your answer. ;)